# Need to trigger a pipeline to different Azure Cloud resources in different run

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake-gen2

We have setup Data Factory pipelines in Azure DevOps. We are planning to deploy two different Data Factories. So, we want if we run a pipeline for the first time then it will use first Azure Data Factory resources (You can say it as DV01) and when any other user trigger that same pipeline parallelly then it will use other Azure Data Factory resource (You can say DV02).

Two different resources combined can be say as DV01 (It contains ADF, Data Lake, Blob, Virtual Machines etc) and DV02 (It will also conatin different ADF, Data Lake, Blob, Virtual Machines etc.)

How we can achieve this as we are using multiple resources (like ADF, Data Lake, Blob, Virtual Machines etc) in Azure Cloud to perform operation in pipeline?

Comment: What task are you using to deploy to Data Factory in Azrue DevOps? Can you share the current build definition with us?

Comment: This is the build definition -

name: CI.Gated
trigger: none
variables:
- name: system.debug
  value: false

stages:
- stage: Gated_Build
  displayName: Gated Build
  variables:
  - group: Vars.DataFlow.BLD
  jobs:
  - job: Gated_Build
    displayName: Gated Build
    timeoutInMinutes: 90
    variables:
    - group: Vars.SQL.bld
    - group: Vars.ADF.bld
    pool:
      vmImage: windows-2019
    steps:
    - checkout: self
    - template: sql-gated-ci.yml
    - template: dw-gated-ci.yml
    - template: adf-gated-ci.yml

Comment: Hi @Prateek Porwal. Did you define the data factory source in the template? For example: first trigger run the sql-gated-ci.yml  ,  next trigger run dw-gated-ci.yml.  Can you help me confrim the process

Comment: Hi @KevinLu-MSFT , In a single trigger of a pipeline, each yaml will run.

Comment: So how do you deploy to different Data Factories? Where do you set this value? We could use condition to do this feature. Please share it with me.

Comment: We want that if we run our pipeline first time then it will go to Dev01 environment (which contains multiple Azure Resources in DV01 Resource Group) and when another user run it second time then it will go to Dev02 environment (Resource Group can be named as DV02 which contains different Azure resources.)

Comment: Hi @KevinLu-MSFT.. I'll come back to you with more details.

Comment: Do you mean that you define the different Resource Group in task? Please share this detail with me . I suggest that you could update your ticket with these info

Comment: Right now we have only one environment setup completely. Now, we are planning to setup a new environment for different parallel jobs.

Comment: Since I can’t fully understand your deployment process, I shared how to judge whether it’s the first run. Then it will trigger the related job.

Answer (score 0):

> we are planning to setup a new environment for different parallel jobs.

Based on your requirement, you want to set another job to deploy DV02.

Please refer to the following sample:

```
name: $(Rev:r)

trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest




stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: A1
    condition: eq(variables['build.buildnumber'], '1')
    steps:
     - checkout: self
  - job: A2
    condition: ne(variables['build.buildnumber'], '1')
    steps:
     - task: PowerShell@2
       inputs:
         targetType: 'inline'
         script: |
           # Write your PowerShell commands here.
           
           Write-Host "Hello World"
```

You could define the variable build.buildnumber(`name: $(Rev:r)`).It will count according to the pipeline run.

When the pipeline is triggered for the first time, the value will be 1. Then you could add the condition in each job.

When the value is 1, it will run the first job. Or it will run another job.

Here is the doc about [condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) and [build.buildnumber](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables-devops-services).

Comment: @PrateekPorwal. Please change to use **AGENT.MACHINENAME**.Agent.name is not a variable.

Comment: condition: eq(variables['Agent.Name'], 'agent-01')

If I am passing this condition, then variables[Agent.Name] is giving Null value and the pipeline step didn't succeed.

Comment: If I am making it like this then only its working -

`steps:
     - powershell: Write-Host "Hello-Agent3"
       condition: eq(variables['Agent.Name'], 'hbi-agent-03')
`

Comment: AGENT.MACHINENAME is also producing the same Null value. 

When I placed condition statement below PowerShell module then its working but then its of no use.

Comment: Hi @PrateekPorwal. Where are you setting this expression? this variable could work under the **steps** parameters.

Comment: Hi, I am using it in Jobs section as you mentioned in the above code snippet.

Comment: Get it. In this case, the agent is not running yet, so this variable cannot be obtained yet